# WordPress REST Upload Media

Tags: uploads, media, rest-api

How to Upload Media via the [WP REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/media/) ?

I am trying to upload media to

```
http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media
```

using POSTMAN.

I tried uploading image using the following headers

```
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=name.jpeg
```

and the payload I am sending is

```
source_url: (file) Uploaded File
post: (text) Post Id
```

and the response that I'm getting is

```
{
    "code": "rest_upload_unknown_error",
    "message": "File is empty. Please upload something more substantial. 
                This error could also be caused by uploads being disabled in your php.ini or 
                by post_max_size being defined as smaller than upload_max_filesize 
                in php.ini.",
    "data": {
        "status": 500
    }
}
```

and When I tried sending the file path instead of the file like

```
source_url: (text) file:///C:/Users/Username/Pictures/01.jpg
post: (text) Post Id
```

I get the response as

```
{
    "code": "rest_upload_no_data",
    "message": "No data supplied.",
    "data": {
        "status": 400
    }
}
```

I tried uploading image via the web dashboard and it works. Just got no clue as to how to make it work via the API.

Any suggestions or help appreciated!
Thank You!

Comment: Where did you read that you should send `source_url` and `post` as the payload? That doesn't sound correct at all. You should just pass the file itself in the body. See also [this duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37432114/wp-rest-api-upload-image).

Comment: @swissspidy I did referred to that question, could you tell me how to send the file in the body? I mean what key should be assigned to the file so that I could test it via POSTMAN?

Comment: What key? There's no key when you select "binary" for the body.

Comment: @swissspidy finally i was able to upload media, I used the key as `file` instead of `source_url`

Answer (score 2):

If you still don't have a solution using Postman, I was able to send .png format image by configuring with these headers in POST:

[image: Postman Headers Wordpress API V2 Media Upload]

And then in the body you select the binary option. So that worked for me.
[image: Postman Body Wordpress API V2 Media Upload]

Comment: just curious, how would I proceed with making it Binary instead of Form when I do the call from my nextjs app? Is there a header parameter to add or will I convert my file upload to binary?